# Storing a Liferay 7 portlet preference using a JSF selectOneListbox

Tags: jsf, liferay, liferay-dxp

I'm upgrading a JSF portlet we had in Liferay 6.2 to Liferay 7.

The portlet displays a list of icons and a `selectOneListbox` used to control how those icons are displayed.

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="listModeSelector" value="#{user.listMode}" size="1">
    <f:selectItems value="#{user.listModes}" var="mode"
        itemLabel="#{mode.label}" itemValue="#{mode.value}" />
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render=":metricsPanel" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

When `user.setListMode` is called after a change to the `selectOneListbox`, the portlet would save the new option to portlet preferences, with a call to the bean's PortletPreferences' `setValue` and `store` functions:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class User {
    private static final String LIST_MODE_KEY = "listMode";
    private ListMode listMode;
    private PortletPreferences preferences;

    public User() {
        PortletRequest request = ((PortletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest());
        preferences = request.getPreferences();
        listMode = ListMode.fromValue( preferences.getValue( LIST_MODE_KEY, ListMode.Normal.getValue() ) );
    }

    public String getListMode() {
        return listMode.getValue();
    }

    public ListMode[] getListModes() {
        return ListMode.values();
    }

    public void setListMode( String listModeValue ) {
        this.listMode = ListMode.fromValue( listModeValue );
        try { 
            preferences.setValue( LIST_MODE_KEY, listModeValue );
            preferences.store();
        }
        catch ( ...Exception e ) {
            log.error( "unable to persist listMode: " + e.getMessage(), e );
        }

    }

}
```

When they change this setting, we want it to stay changed for them, for any future sessions. But since moving to Liferay 7, doing this causes an `IllegalStateException` with the message `Preferences cannot be stored inside a render call`.

So my question is: in Liferay 7 JSF, is there a way to store `PortletPreferences` from a change to an item like a `selectOneListbox`, rather than submitting a form?  If not, what would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: Can you add a bit of code? I mean, how do you bind your bean to the `selectOneListbox`? I'm running JSF on Liferay 7 as well and everything before the _Render Response Phase_ is still called in the action call of the portlet.

Comment: Added my xhtml and bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use the portlet preferences of the *current* request. As you use the preferences from the constructor of your session bean, which is usually called from the render request first, the preferences are still connected with the (outdated) render request.

I mean like this:

```
public void setListMode( String listModeValue ) {
    this.listMode = ListMode.fromValue( listModeValue );
    try { 
        PortletPreferences preferences = ((PortletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getPreferences();
        preferences.setValue( LIST_MODE_KEY, listModeValue );
        preferences.store();
    }
    ...
}
```